# Swagger UI with Apache Camel without Spring Boot

Tags: java, apache-camel, swagger

I'm following the [example](https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/master/examples/camel-example-swagger-cdi) on Apache Camel's GitHub on how to use Camel with Swagger.

It works fine for me and I can see the Swagger API in JSON format by going to http://localhost:8080/api-doc

How do I add the Swagger UI on top of this? I don't want to use Spring Boot for this either.

I can't see any examples on their GitHub or in the documentation.

Comment: you've gotten further along than I. The best I can get is a 204 response from the swagger endpoint.

Comment: Haha! If you post your issue as a question I'll take a look and might be able to help. I'm getting close to getting something working with the UI too.

Comment: w00t - but let me ask the easy one before I post a new thing. when I implement the example in one of my routes, I get a 204 response from what should be the endpoint. something is definitely wired in - there's just no content coming back, json, UI, or otherwise. would you be able to post your route code so I can check my thing against your, more functional, implementation?